# How to programatically create pages in AEM with editable template

Tags: aem, aem-6, aem-touch-ui

I am used to work with the pagemanager to create pages:

`pageManager.create(parentPath, name, template, title, false);`

This works with normal templates stored in /apps. Since Adobe recommends to use editable templates (stored in /conf), the above approach does not work: It creates the page but without the template attached to the node. Is it a bug or is there another approach how to create pages based on editable templates?

Answer (score 2):

That was a stupid one, sorry for asking. Resolution: Read-rights must be given for /conf.

Comment: It was not stupid actually, I've just lost half-hour trying to realize what's the issue and permissions were not on my list. This is a completely valid problem and resolution.